# picking a random char from an array

Tags: c

I was wondering if there is a way of randomly picking a character from the following array in C but only picking each character once....

```
const char characters[13][4] =
                    {   'A' , 'B' , 'C' , 'D' , 'E' , 'F' , 'G' , 'H' , 'I' ,
                        'J' , 'K' , 'L' ,'M' , 'N' , 'O' , 'P' , 'Q' , 'R' ,
                        'S' , 'T' , 'U' , 'V' , 'W' , 'X' , 'Y', 'Z', 

                        'A' , 'B' , 'C' , 'D' , 'E' , 'F' , 'G' , 'H' , 'I' ,
                        'J' , 'K' , 'L' , 'M'  , 'N' ,'O' , 'P' , 'Q' , 'R' ,
                        'S' , 'T' , 'U' , 'V' , 'W' , 'X' , 'Y', 'Z'

                    };
```

Comment: You mean that it should print the Whole array? or just some part of it?

Comment: Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: the whole array but I want to print each item randomly just once. Thx

Comment: Why do you have an array of arrays instead of a single array?

Comment: As for your problem, can you modify the "array" as you pick characters from it?

Comment: yes , I mean I just want a random one and I want to use that once

Answer (score 3):

When you pick a character, just remove it from the set:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

char getRandomChar(char *set) {
    size_t len = strlen(set);
    if (len == 0) {
        /* We are all out of characters */
        return -1;
    }
    /* Select a character at random */
    int rv = rand() % len;
    char ret = set[rv];
    /* Remove the selected character from the set */
    set[rv] = set[len -1];
    set[len -1] = '\0';
    /* Return the character */
    return ret;
}

int main(void) {
    char set[27] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    char randomChar;

    /* Intialize random number generator */
   srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    while ((randomChar = getRandomChar(set)) != -1) {
        printf("Selected %c. Remaining: %s\n", randomChar, set);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the code can handle that the same character occurs more than one time. If you want each character to be drawn twice, use the starting set `"AABBCCDDEEFFGGHHIIJJKKLLMMNNOOPPQQRRSSTTUUVVWWXXYYZZ"`.

Comment: Your code is broken. Some headers are missing and [That's not all](http://pastebin.com/raw/qGzuHpxk)

Comment: Thanks for the fish. I'll come back tomorrow for more. Salmon this time. Five of them. If you have them ready for me before noon, that's acceptable.

Comment: @Lundin I didn't answer because of the quality of the question (which is low). I answered because I think it is a problem that is interesting enough to deserve an answer on SO.

Comment: Great answer :D

Comment: Be that as it may, we should not encourage blatant code begging with no effort by the OP. If you wish to share this answer with SO, I would instead suggest that you post a community wiki question and answer it yourself.

Comment: 1) return of `strlen` is `size_t` and not `int`. -=- 2) `int len = strlen(set);`  ==>>> `size_t len = strlen(set);`  3) -=- `srand(time(NULL));` shouldn't be `srand( (unsigned) time(NULL));`?

Comment: @Michi Thanks again. I don't think it would be a problem on any sane platform, but hey, this is SO, so might as well make it clean even for the `-pedantic` compiler.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the characters, then randomly pick a character, if it's not zero (or something) then you have the character and you get it and set the entry to zero (or something). If it is zero (or something) then loop and pick another character.

If you can't modify the original characters, have another "array" that contains a boolean value if a certain character has been picked or not. It should mirror the dimensions of the `characters` arrays and you check that if a character has been picked or not.